# React router ignores URL after // for multiple optional parameters

Tags: react-router-v4

I want to match this url https://localhost:8050/search/Contact//* to the path given below.

```
    <Route path="/search/:type?/:subType?/:query?" component={TestComponent}?>
```

As subtype is optional parameter so I am passing blank instead.
But the "query" parameter is ignored all together.

I get match as follows in props

```
match {
    params: {type: "Contact", subType: undefined, query: undefined}
    path: "/search/:type?/:subType?/:query?"
    url: "/search/Contact"
}
```

I want * to be mapped with query  in match params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using :subType then remove it or use 2 different routes.

```
<Route exact path="/search/:type?/:query?" component={TestComponent}?> 
<Route path="/search/:type?/:subType?/:query?" component={TestComponent}?>
```